# Feature templates in ArcGIS JSAPI published maps

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.3, feature-layer

I have an ArcGIS map which is published on ArcGIS server (10.3) and while the feature templates for each layer are set up in the map, the published map service contains totally different set of feature templates, automatically generated based on all possibilities in the symbology. I use the [TemplatePicker](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/templatepicker-amd.html) class to expose them for my web application and hence do not have much control on what is being shown from the feature templates in the map.

Am I missing something (like an option on publishing) or is there a work around?

Comment: Apparently the `TemplatePicker` can be customized with its `items` parameter to show a custom set, but one should define all the items manually and not rely on the underlying layer which is a possible work around.